# let user join a group only if he is member of another group

Tags: 7, rules, organic-groups

I mean for example in a sub-group structure:

Group1

-Subgroup of Group1

I want to validate that if user wants to join "Subgroup of Group1" he must be member of Group1

how would be the rule?
Thank you

Comment: Interesting question/challenge (+1!) ... Instead of "validating" the user is member of Group1, would it be OK to just automatically "make him member of that group (if he is not)"?